# Return List of <T> from firestore collections

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I return a List of type T from firestore collections? Here is where I get which result in an error because the return type is of type `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`

```
  Future<List<T>> getCollections<T>(String path) async {
    final data = await Firestore.instance.collection(path).getDocuments();
    final result = data.documents.map((doc) => doc.data).toList();
    return result;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: @pskink that result in error at `doc.data` because Map<String, dynamic> isn't type of T

Comment: @pskink please see screenshot in my updated question

Comment: know that Firebase always gives you Map<String,dynamic>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
final result = data.documents.map<T>((doc) => doc.data as T);
```

Comment: Thanks.. that worked.. however it doesn't't do what I need.. but that is for another question